# How to save JFrame Contents to File

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to make a program that asks the user for information and then when they click save, the text boxes and labels and all are saved into a file to be able to be shared. It could be any type of file if need be. The information is in a Tabbed pane inside a JFrame. Here is my current save method.

```
FileFilter ft = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text Files", "txt", "jpg","png", "jpeg");
    db.addChoosableFileFilter(ft);
    int returnVal = db.showSaveDialog(this);

    if (returnVal == javax.swing.JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        java.io.File saved_file = db.getSelectedFile();
        String file_name = saved_file.toString();

        try {
            WriteFile data = new WriteFile(file_name, false);
            String allText = JFrame.toString(); //Line im having trouble with
            data.writeToFile(allText);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to save the JFrame in a way that it can be reconstructed again by another program? I don't think you can do it that way, I'm assuming that line only saves the instance text representation. If you want to save and reconstruct a JFrame, you'll need to save the data being used (in the labels and boxes) and write code to parse and reconstruct from the saved data.

Comment: This is why you should build the logic model for your application before adding a GUI to it.

Comment: Post [mcve] of your `JFrame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JFrame.toString` wont give you any state that you want to save.

The right approach is to get each value from text boxes and save/reload manually into a file.

Another approach that you can try, is to serialize the whole JFrame into a file. Look at this [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) for more info.

Comment: I feared I had to do it manually. I'll look into the Java Doc though. Thank you.